# How to show a specific part of website on Webview? (Xcode 7 Swift 2)

Tags: html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I'm trying to make an app from my schools website that shows the teachers directory. The problem with only using a uiwebview and loading the website is that the website isn't optimized for mobile, so all the extra headers and side panels are showing. I only want the middle specific part of the website. I located the div and all that but can't seem to only show the middle content of the site instead of the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

Get the html content and then strip the tags which you don't need and pass it to webview

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourwebsite.com"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

   NSLog(@"String is %@",string);
  //String will contain the whole tags. Just strip the content in string which you want and pass it to webview

[self.webview loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
```